# Bouncy Castle - This certificate has an invalid digital signature

Tags: ssl-certificate, bouncycastle

I have been generating self-signed certificates using bouncy castle and everything was going well until I updated the win7 OS running on my computer A.  After the update the certificate gives me the following error when viewing it using CERTMGR : This certificate has an invalid digital signature.

The same certificate does not give errors on another computer (B) that did not receive the security updates from Microsoft.  I then generated a fresh certificate on B with no errors and then installed it on A and the same error occurs. (This certificate has an invalid digital signature.)

I went back to bouncy castle and run the code from the example presented in Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.Examples Pkcs12Example and I get different the same results depending on the computer  on A it fails on B it is ok.

Has anyone been having the same problem and what can be done to fix this error?  I do not want to roll back computer A to remove the microsoft update that introduced this error.  I am looking to find a permanent fix if it is possible

```
    namespace Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.Examples
{
    /**
    * Example of how to set up a certificate chain and a PKCS 12 store for
    * a private individual - obviously you'll need to generate your own keys,
    * and you may need to add a NetscapeCertType extension or add a key
    * usage extension depending on your application, but you should get the
    * idea! As always this is just an example...
    */
    public class Pkcs12Example
    {
        private static readonly char[] passwd = "hello world".ToCharArray();

        private static readonly X509V1CertificateGenerator v1CertGen = new X509V1CertificateGenerator();
        private static readonly X509V3CertificateGenerator v3CertGen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

        /**
        * we generate the CA's certificate
        */
        public static X509CertificateEntry CreateMasterCert(
            AsymmetricKeyParameter  pubKey,
            AsymmetricKeyParameter  privKey)
        {
            //
            // signers name
            //
            string issuer = "C=AU, O=The Legion of the Bouncy Castle, OU=Bouncy Primary Certificate";

            //
            // subjects name - the same as we are self signed.
            //
            string subject = "C=AU, O=The Legion of the Bouncy Castle, OU=Bouncy Primary Certificate";

            //
            // create the certificate - version 1
            //

            v1CertGen.SetSerialNumber(BigInteger.One);
            v1CertGen.SetIssuerDN(new X509Name(issuer));
            v1CertGen.SetNotBefore(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-1));
            v1CertGen.SetNotAfter(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1));
            v1CertGen.SetSubjectDN(new X509Name(subject));
            v1CertGen.SetPublicKey(pubKey);
            v1CertGen.SetSignatureAlgorithm("SHA1WithRSAEncryption");

            X509Certificate cert = v1CertGen.Generate(privKey);

            cert.CheckValidity(DateTime.UtcNow);

            cert.Verify(pubKey);

//          PKCS12BagAttributeCarrier   bagAttr = (PKCS12BagAttributeCarrier)cert;
            IDictionary bagAttr = new Hashtable();

            //
            // this is actually optional - but if you want to have control
            // over setting the friendly name this is the way to do it...
            //
//          bagAttr.setBagAttribute(
//              PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_friendlyName,
//              new DERBMPString("Bouncy Primary Certificate"));
            bagAttr.Add(PkcsObjectIdentifiers.Pkcs9AtFriendlyName.Id,
                new DerBmpString("Bouncy Primary Certificate"));

            return new X509CertificateEntry(cert, bagAttr);
        }

        /**
        * we generate an intermediate certificate signed by our CA
        */
        public static X509CertificateEntry CreateIntermediateCert(
            AsymmetricKeyParameter  pubKey,
            AsymmetricKeyParameter  caPrivKey,
            X509Certificate         caCert)
        {
            //
            // subject name table.
            //
            IDictionary attrs = new Hashtable();
            IList order = new ArrayList();

            attrs.Add(X509Name.C, "AU");
            attrs.Add(X509Name.O, "The Legion of the Bouncy Castle");
            attrs.Add(X509Name.OU, "Bouncy Intermediate Certificate");
            attrs.Add(X509Name.EmailAddress, "feedback-crypto@bouncycastle.org");

            order.Add(X509Name.C);
            order.Add(X509Name.O);
            order.Add(X509Name.OU);
            order.Add(X509Name.EmailAddress);

            //
            // create the certificate - version 3
            //
            v3CertGen.Reset();

            v3CertGen.SetSerialNumber(BigInteger.Two);
            v3CertGen.SetIssuerDN(PrincipalUtilities.GetSubjectX509Principal(caCert));
            v3CertGen.SetNotBefore(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-1));
            v3CertGen.SetNotAfter(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1));
            v3CertGen.SetSubjectDN(new X509Name(order, attrs));
            v3CertGen.SetPublicKey(pubKey);
            v3CertGen.SetSignatureAlgorithm("SHA1WithRSAEncryption");

            //
            // extensions
            //
            v3CertGen.AddExtension(
                X509Extensions.SubjectKeyIdentifier,
                false,
                new SubjectKeyIdentifierStructure(pubKey));

            v3CertGen.AddExtension(
                X509Extensions.AuthorityKeyIdentifier,
                false,
                new AuthorityKeyIdentifierStructure(caCert));

            v3CertGen.AddExtension(
                X509Extensions.BasicConstraints,
                true,
                new BasicConstraints(0));

            X509Certificate cert = v3CertGen.Generate(caPrivKey);

            cert.CheckValidity(DateTime.UtcNow);

            cert.Verify(caCert.GetPublicKey());


            IDictionary bagAttr = new Hashtable();


            bagAttr.Add(PkcsObjectIdentifiers.Pkcs9AtFriendlyName.Id,
                new DerBmpString("Bouncy Intermediate Certificate"));

            return new X509CertificateEntry(cert, bagAttr);
        }

        /**
        * we generate a certificate signed by our CA's intermediate certificate
        */
        public static X509CertificateEntry CreateCert(
            AsymmetricKeyParameter  pubKey,
            AsymmetricKeyParameter  caPrivKey,
            AsymmetricKeyParameter  caPubKey)
        {
            //
            // signers name table.
            //
            IDictionary sAttrs = new Hashtable();
            IList sOrder = new ArrayList();

            sAttrs.Add(X509Name.C, "AU");
            sAttrs.Add(X509Name.O, "The Legion of the Bouncy Castle");
            sAttrs.Add(X509Name.OU, "Bouncy Intermediate Certificate");
            sAttrs.Add(X509Name.EmailAddress, "feedback-crypto@bouncycastle.org");

            sOrder.Add(X509Name.C);
            sOrder.Add(X509Name.O);
            sOrder.Add(X509Name.OU);
            sOrder.Add(X509Name.EmailAddress);

            //
            // subjects name table.
            //
            IDictionary attrs = new Hashtable();
            IList order = new ArrayList();

            attrs.Add(X509Name.C, "AU");
            attrs.Add(X509Name.O, "The Legion of the Bouncy Castle");
            attrs.Add(X509Name.L, "Melbourne");
            attrs.Add(X509Name.CN, "Eric H. Echidna");
            attrs.Add(X509Name.EmailAddress, "feedback-crypto@bouncycastle.org");

            order.Add(X509Name.C);
            order.Add(X509Name.O);
            order.Add(X509Name.L);
            order.Add(X509Name.CN);
            order.Add(X509Name.EmailAddress);

            //
            // create the certificate - version 3
            //
            v3CertGen.Reset();

            v3CertGen.SetSerialNumber(BigInteger.Three);
            v3CertGen.SetIssuerDN(new X509Name(sOrder, sAttrs));
            v3CertGen.SetNotBefore(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-1));
            v3CertGen.SetNotAfter(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1));
            v3CertGen.SetSubjectDN(new X509Name(order, attrs));
            v3CertGen.SetPublicKey(pubKey);
            v3CertGen.SetSignatureAlgorithm("SHA1WithRSAEncryption");

            //
            // add the extensions
            //
            v3CertGen.AddExtension(
                X509Extensions.SubjectKeyIdentifier,
                false,
                new SubjectKeyIdentifierStructure(pubKey));

            v3CertGen.AddExtension(
                X509Extensions.AuthorityKeyIdentifier,
                false,
                new AuthorityKeyIdentifierStructure(caPubKey));

            X509Certificate cert = v3CertGen.Generate(caPrivKey);

            cert.CheckValidity(DateTime.UtcNow);

            cert.Verify(caPubKey);

            IDictionary bagAttr = new Hashtable();


            bagAttr.Add(PkcsObjectIdentifiers.Pkcs9AtFriendlyName.Id,
                new DerBmpString("Eric's Key"));
            bagAttr.Add(PkcsObjectIdentifiers.Pkcs9AtLocalKeyID.Id,
                new SubjectKeyIdentifierStructure(pubKey));

            return new X509CertificateEntry(cert, bagAttr);
        }

        public static void Main(
            string[] args)
        {
//          Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

            //
            // personal keys
            //
//          RSAPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(
            RsaKeyParameters pubKey = new RsaKeyParameters(false,
                new BigInteger("b4a7e46170574f16a97082b22be58b6a2a629798419be12872a4bdba626cfae9900f76abfb12139dce5de56564fab2b6543165a040c606887420e33d91ed7ed7", 16),
                new BigInteger("11", 16));

//          RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec privKeySpec = new RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec(
            RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters privKey = new RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters(
                new BigInteger("b4a7e46170574f16a97082b22be58b6a2a629798419be12872a4bdba626cfae9900f76abfb12139dce5de56564fab2b6543165a040c606887420e33d91ed7ed7", 16),
                new BigInteger("11", 16),
                new BigInteger("9f66f6b05410cd503b2709e88115d55daced94d1a34d4e32bf824d0dde6028ae79c5f07b580f5dce240d7111f7ddb130a7945cd7d957d1920994da389f490c89", 16),
                new BigInteger("c0a0758cdf14256f78d4708c86becdead1b50ad4ad6c5c703e2168fbf37884cb", 16),
                new BigInteger("f01734d7960ea60070f1b06f2bb81bfac48ff192ae18451d5e56c734a5aab8a5", 16),
                new BigInteger("b54bb9edff22051d9ee60f9351a48591b6500a319429c069a3e335a1d6171391", 16),
                new BigInteger("d3d83daf2a0cecd3367ae6f8ae1aeb82e9ac2f816c6fc483533d8297dd7884cd", 16),
                new BigInteger("b8f52fc6f38593dabb661d3f50f8897f8106eee68b1bce78a95b132b4e5b5d19", 16));

            //
            // intermediate keys.
            //
//          RSAPublicKeySpec intPubKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(
            RsaKeyParameters intPubKey = new RsaKeyParameters(false,
                new BigInteger("8de0d113c5e736969c8d2b047a243f8fe18edad64cde9e842d3669230ca486f7cfdde1f8eec54d1905fff04acc85e61093e180cadc6cea407f193d44bb0e9449b8dbb49784cd9e36260c39e06a947299978c6ed8300724e887198cfede20f3fbde658fa2bd078be946a392bd349f2b49c486e20c405588e306706c9017308e69", 16),
                new BigInteger("ffff", 16));


//          RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec intPrivKeySpec = new RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec(
            RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters intPrivKey = new RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters(
                new BigInteger("8de0d113c5e736969c8d2b047a243f8fe18edad64cde9e842d3669230ca486f7cfdde1f8eec54d1905fff04acc85e61093e180cadc6cea407f193d44bb0e9449b8dbb49784cd9e36260c39e06a947299978c6ed8300724e887198cfede20f3fbde658fa2bd078be946a392bd349f2b49c486e20c405588e306706c9017308e69", 16),
                new BigInteger("ffff", 16),
                new BigInteger("7deb1b194a85bcfd29cf871411468adbc987650903e3bacc8338c449ca7b32efd39ffc33bc84412fcd7df18d23ce9d7c25ea910b1ae9985373e0273b4dca7f2e0db3b7314056ac67fd277f8f89cf2fd73c34c6ca69f9ba477143d2b0e2445548aa0b4a8473095182631da46844c356f5e5c7522eb54b5a33f11d730ead9c0cff", 16),
                new BigInteger("ef4cede573cea47f83699b814de4302edb60eefe426c52e17bd7870ec7c6b7a24fe55282ebb73775f369157726fcfb988def2b40350bdca9e5b418340288f649", 16),
                new BigInteger("97c7737d1b9a0088c3c7b528539247fd2a1593e7e01cef18848755be82f4a45aa093276cb0cbf118cb41117540a78f3fc471ba5d69f0042274defc9161265721", 16),
                new BigInteger("6c641094e24d172728b8da3c2777e69adfd0839085be7e38c7c4a2dd00b1ae969f2ec9d23e7e37090fcd449a40af0ed463fe1c612d6810d6b4f58b7bfa31eb5f", 16),
                new BigInteger("70b7123e8e69dfa76feb1236d0a686144b00e9232ed52b73847e74ef3af71fb45ccb24261f40d27f98101e230cf27b977a5d5f1f15f6cf48d5cb1da2a3a3b87f", 16),
                new BigInteger("e38f5750d97e270996a286df2e653fd26c242106436f5bab0f4c7a9e654ce02665d5a281f2c412456f2d1fa26586ef04a9adac9004ca7f913162cb28e13bf40d", 16));

            //
            // ca keys
            //
//          RSAPublicKeySpec caPubKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(
            RsaKeyParameters caPubKey = new RsaKeyParameters(false,
                new BigInteger("b259d2d6e627a768c94be36164c2d9fc79d97aab9253140e5bf17751197731d6f7540d2509e7b9ffee0a70a6e26d56e92d2edd7f85aba85600b69089f35f6bdbf3c298e05842535d9f064e6b0391cb7d306e0a2d20c4dfb4e7b49a9640bdea26c10ad69c3f05007ce2513cee44cfe01998e62b6c3637d3fc0391079b26ee36d5", 16),
                new BigInteger("11", 16));

//          RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec   caPrivKeySpec = new RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec(
            RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters caPrivKey = new RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters(
                new BigInteger("b259d2d6e627a768c94be36164c2d9fc79d97aab9253140e5bf17751197731d6f7540d2509e7b9ffee0a70a6e26d56e92d2edd7f85aba85600b69089f35f6bdbf3c298e05842535d9f064e6b0391cb7d306e0a2d20c4dfb4e7b49a9640bdea26c10ad69c3f05007ce2513cee44cfe01998e62b6c3637d3fc0391079b26ee36d5", 16),
                new BigInteger("11", 16),
                new BigInteger("92e08f83cc9920746989ca5034dcb384a094fb9c5a6288fcc4304424ab8f56388f72652d8fafc65a4b9020896f2cde297080f2a540e7b7ce5af0b3446e1258d1dd7f245cf54124b4c6e17da21b90a0ebd22605e6f45c9f136d7a13eaac1c0f7487de8bd6d924972408ebb58af71e76fd7b012a8d0e165f3ae2e5077a8648e619", 16),
                new BigInteger("f75e80839b9b9379f1cf1128f321639757dba514642c206bbbd99f9a4846208b3e93fbbe5e0527cc59b1d4b929d9555853004c7c8b30ee6a213c3d1bb7415d03", 16),
                new BigInteger("b892d9ebdbfc37e397256dd8a5d3123534d1f03726284743ddc6be3a709edb696fc40c7d902ed804c6eee730eee3d5b20bf6bd8d87a296813c87d3b3cc9d7947", 16),
                new BigInteger("1d1a2d3ca8e52068b3094d501c9a842fec37f54db16e9a67070a8b3f53cc03d4257ad252a1a640eadd603724d7bf3737914b544ae332eedf4f34436cac25ceb5", 16),
                new BigInteger("6c929e4e81672fef49d9c825163fec97c4b7ba7acb26c0824638ac22605d7201c94625770984f78a56e6e25904fe7db407099cad9b14588841b94f5ab498dded", 16),
                new BigInteger("dae7651ee69ad1d081ec5e7188ae126f6004ff39556bde90e0b870962fa7b926d070686d8244fe5a9aa709a95686a104614834b0ada4b10f53197a5cb4c97339", 16));



            //
            // set up the keys
            //
//          KeyFactory          fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
//          PrivateKey          caPrivKey = fact.generatePrivate(caPrivKeySpec);
//          PublicKey           caPubKey = fact.generatePublic(caPubKeySpec);
//          PrivateKey          intPrivKey = fact.generatePrivate(intPrivKeySpec);
//          PublicKey           intPubKey = fact.generatePublic(intPubKeySpec);
//          PrivateKey          privKey = fact.generatePrivate(privKeySpec);
//          PublicKey           pubKey = fact.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);

            X509CertificateEntry[] chain = new X509CertificateEntry[3];

            chain[2] = CreateMasterCert(caPubKey, caPrivKey);
            chain[1] = CreateIntermediateCert(intPubKey, caPrivKey, chain[2].Certificate);
            chain[0] = CreateCert(pubKey, intPrivKey, intPubKey);

            IDictionary bagAttr = new Hashtable();
            bagAttr.Add(PkcsObjectIdentifiers.Pkcs9AtFriendlyName.Id,
                new DerBmpString("Eric's Key"));
            bagAttr.Add(PkcsObjectIdentifiers.Pkcs9AtLocalKeyID.Id,
                new SubjectKeyIdentifierStructure(pubKey));

            //
            // store the key and the certificate chain
            //
//          KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
//          store.load(null, null);
            Pkcs12Store store = new Pkcs12StoreBuilder().Build();

            //
            // if you haven't set the friendly name and local key id above
            // the name below will be the name of the key
            //
            store.SetKeyEntry("Eric's Key", new AsymmetricKeyEntry(privKey, bagAttr), chain);

//          FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream("id.p12");
//
//          store.store(fOut, passwd);
            FileStream fOut = File.Create("id.p12");
            store.Save(fOut, passwd, new SecureRandom());
            fOut.Close();



            X509Certificate cert2 = chain[2].Certificate;
            // convert to "Microsoft" x509cert.
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate newcert2 = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.ToX509Certificate(cert2);
            //convert to Microsoft X509Certificate to Microsoft X509Certificate2 
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 netcert2 = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(newcert2);
            netcert2.FriendlyName = "AAAA root certificate";
            PutCertificateInstore(netcert2);

            X509Certificate cert1 = chain[1].Certificate;
            // convert to "Microsoft" x509cert.
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate newcert1 = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.ToX509Certificate(cert1);
            //convert to Microsoft X509Certificate to Microsoft X509Certificate2 
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 netcert1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(newcert1);
            netcert1.FriendlyName = "AAAA Intermediate Certificate";
            PutCertificateInstore(netcert1);

            X509Certificate cert0 = chain[0].Certificate;
            // convert to "Microsoft" x509cert.
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate newcert0 = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.ToX509Certificate(cert0);
            //convert to Microsoft X509Certificate to Microsoft X509Certificate2 
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 netcert0 = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(newcert0);
            netcert0.FriendlyName = "AAAA key for hostName: " ;
            PutCertificateInstore(netcert0);






        }

        public static void PutCertificateInstore(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 ServerCertificate)
        {
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store store = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.AuthRoot, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            store.Add(ServerCertificate);
            store.Close();

        }

        private static void CreateCertNew(out System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider rcsp, out System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 importcert)
        {
            X509Name x2 = new X509Name("CN=Some Root CA, C=NL, OU=BleedingEdge, ST=Somewhere, L=Somelane");
            RsaKeyPairGenerator rkpg = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
            rkpg.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 2048));
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair ackp = rkpg.GenerateKeyPair();

            RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters rsaprivkey = ((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)ackp.Private);

            ArrayList us = new ArrayList
                                    {
                                        KeyPurposeID.IdKPCodeSigning,
                                        KeyPurposeID.IdKPEmailProtection,
                                        KeyPurposeID.IdKPIpsecEndSystem,
                                        KeyPurposeID.IdKPIpsecTunnel,
                                        KeyPurposeID.IdKPServerAuth,
                                        KeyPurposeID.IdKPTimeStamping,
                                        KeyPurposeID.IdKPOcspSigning,
                                        KeyPurposeID.IdKPClientAuth,
                                        KeyPurposeID.IdKPIpsecUser
                                    };



            X509V3CertificateGenerator certgen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
            certgen.SetIssuerDN(x2);
            certgen.SetSubjectDN(x2);
            certgen.SetPublicKey(ackp.Public);
            certgen.SetSerialNumber(new BigInteger("1"));
            certgen.SetSignatureAlgorithm("SHA1WITHRSA");
            certgen.SetNotAfter(DateTime.Today.AddYears(10));
            certgen.SetNotBefore(DateTime.Today);
            certgen.AddExtension(X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage, false, new ExtendedKeyUsage(us));
            certgen.AddExtension(X509Extensions.KeyUsage, true,
                                    new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.CrlSign | KeyUsage.KeyCertSign));
            certgen.AddExtension(X509Extensions.BasicConstraints, true, new BasicConstraints(true));
            X509Certificate cert = certgen.Generate(ackp.Private);

            System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters cparms = new System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters
            {
                CryptoKeySecurity = new System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeySecurity(),
                Flags = System.Security.Cryptography.CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore,
            };

            rcsp = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider(cparms);

            System.Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters parms = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters
            {
                Modulus = rsaprivkey.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
                P = rsaprivkey.P.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
                Q = rsaprivkey.Q.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
                DP = rsaprivkey.DP.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
                DQ = rsaprivkey.DQ.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
                InverseQ = rsaprivkey.QInv.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
                D = rsaprivkey.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
                Exponent = rsaprivkey.PublicExponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned()
            };

            rcsp.ImportParameters(parms);

            importcert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(DotNetUtilities.ToX509Certificate(cert));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*The same certificate does not give errors on another computer (B) that did not receive the security updates from Microsoft.*" Can you upload an example certificate somewhere for us to look at? Sounds like the issue may have nothing to do with BouncyCastle.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking at this. Here is a link where a certificate has been loaded "https://skydrive.live.com/?sc=documents&cid=c315f9ed36356212#cid=C315F9ED36356212&id=C315F9ED36356212%21105

Answer (score 2):

Doing some testing with PKCS12-Certificates on my own I might have gotten an idea concerning your/my problem.

I get the mentioned error concerning an invalid signature for any end certificate if there either is no registered root certificate at all or the registered root certificate does not match the one of the current certificate chain (old version).

If there is no registered root certificate it will just state that it can not validate the signature.

If there indeed is a matching root certificate it will state that the signature is valid.

Comment: if it is an incomplete chain of trust then can you tell me if you see the problems for this certificate chain.

Comment: Number of chain elements: 3

<-- Host Cert
Element issuer name: OU=ServerName, O=ServerName
Element certificate valid until: 11/29/2012 9:32:27 PM
Element certificate is valid: False
Element error status length: 2
Element information: 
Number of element extensions: 2

Satus: NotSignatureValid
StatusInformation The signature of the certificate cannot be verified.

Satus: 1048576
StatusInformation:  Unknown error.

Name of the certification authority that issued the certificate: OU=ServerName, O=ServerName
Has Private key: False

Comment: <-- Intermediate Cert
Element issuer name: OU=CAName, O=CAName, C=USA
Element certificate valid until: 11/30/2012 6:14:45 PM
Element certificate is valid: False
Element error status length: 0
Element information: 
Number of element extensions: 3


Name of the certification authority that issued the certificate: OU=CAName, O=CAName, C=USA
Signature algorithm that issued the certificate: System.Security.Cryptography.Oid
Has Private key: False

Comment: <--- Root CA
Element issuer name: OU=CAName, O=CAName, C=USA
Element certificate valid until: 11/30/2012 6:14:44 PM
Element certificate is valid: True
Element error status length: 0
Element information: 
Number of element extensions: 0

Name of the certification authority that issued the certificate: OU=CAName, O=CAName, C=USA
Signature algorithm that issued the certificate: System.Security.Cryptography.Oid
Has Private key: False

Comment: I'm new to Bouncy Castle as well as to Java JCE in general so I'm only guessing. The reason I got across your post is that I have a possibly similar problem with generating X.509 certificates [link to stackoverflow problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13141714/1740926).

Comment: Searching for help I came across a Microsoft page that said something about problems with newer signature algorithms in Win Server 2003 and offered a hotfix. My problems with invalid signatures according to certmgr.msc vanished as soon as I changed the signature algorithm from SHA512WITHRSAANDMGF1 to plain SHA1WITHRSA.

Comment: Concerning my recent edit of my answer and your certificate chain posted in the comments above you might have mixed your certificate chain with different and incompatible versions of your certificates. From what you have posted you would not see any difference between different versions/keys.
I suggest you clean up your certmgr and get rid of all certs from your chain and reimport a clean chain. For future problems check the fingerprints of all certs.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is caused by the 512 bit key size in your personal certificate.  Very close to the time you started observing issues, Microsoft released a security [patch](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2012/09/03/important-upcoming-certificate-changes.aspx) (KB2661254) that blocks RSA key lengths less than 1024 bits.

Try creating your personal certificate with a 1024 bit or higher key length and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I was using the *wrong* **Private Key**, and not the one that was corresponding to the certificate of the CA. Technically, I was generating a new one, and I'm not sure why. It was a silly mistake, but it is worth mentioning because I was trying to find the error for days.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem when signing an intermediate CA's CSR . The mistake I was making was **using** the ***intermediate CA's public key*** as the **AuthorityKeyIdentifier** in the extensions. I changed it to the ***CA's public key*** and left the **subjectKeyIdentifier** as the ***intermediate CA's public key*** which resolved the invalid digital signature.